# Show fields of content type B while keeping filter criteria as content type = A in view

Tags: views

I am creating a website in drupal.

I have two content types first is Article and second is Author

Article contains following fields:
 Title, Body, Author-name, Language

Author has following fields:
 Name, Year, Info

Now In a view I want to show the Article name, its author-name and the year of that author!

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference), In your **Article** content type, create the author field as an entity reference field and refer it to the **Author** content type. After that you can create a view and add a relationship of **Entity Reference** and you will get the related fields. For further read, refer [here](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-entity-reference-module)

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer but I want that field to be a link of the author account! How can I do that?

Comment: Add the referenced entity field and under **Formatter** select **Label** and then check **Link label to the referenced entity**. Thats it you will get the link.